# AWK for files in multiple folders

Tags: bash, awk

I need to use AWK to sort through 1000 folders and extract the 2nd row of the 5th column in a file. We'll call it file.frq. For example:

```
home/user/directory/data1/file.frq
...
home/user/directory/data1000/file.frq
```

file.frq looks like this:

```
 CHR  SNP   A1   A2          MAF  NCHROBS
   3  fa0    A    G         0.22      300
```

I need the output of the AWK script to just list that 1-MAF value (*1-0.22 in this case, so 0.78*) 1000 times for each .`frq` file in each `data` directory. I was playing around with `find`, but it is new to me and I'm not sure it's the right tool.

Comment: `find /home/user/directory -name file.frq -exec awk <awk magic> {} \;` should do it.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'FNR == 2 {print FILENAME, 1 - $5}' data*/file.frq | sort -V
```

If its the second record, print the file name and  1 - the fifth column.  A version sort seems to get proper ordering.

Comment: +1 but put the condition in the condition part of the awk body, not in the action part: `awk '$5 ~ /^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$/{print FILENAME, 1 - $5}' data*/file.frq` and a better way to test for a number would be simply `$5 == $5+0` so `awk '$5 == $5+0{print FILENAME, 1 - $5}' data*/file.frq` but in this case a simple `$5 ~ /[[:digit:]]/` or just `FNR==2` looks like it'd work.

Comment: Unfortunately with this method output is not really sorted numerically e.g. `data1, data1000, data20` (1000 goes before 20)

Comment: I can suggest `awk 'FNR == 2 {print FILENAME, 1 - $5}' $(printf '%s\n' /home/user/directory/data*/file.frq | sort -n -k 1.26)` for start.

Comment: piping the output to `sort --version-sort` seems to work in my test as well

Answer (score 2):

To get only the values:

```
find /home/user/directory/ -name file.frq -exec awk 'FNR == 2 { print 1-$5 }' {} \;
```

To also get the filename in the output:

```
find /home/user/directory/ -name file.frq -exec awk 'FNR == 2 { print FILENAME " " 1-$5 }' {} \;
```

**Edit**

To sort the output in the desired order you could for example pipe the results through:

```
sed s/data// | sort -n | sed s/^/data/
```

or shorter:

```
sort -ta -k3n
```

Comment: This is super helpful. Here's my next question. The data folders are sorted by name, so the outputs come out in this order:

`data1
 data10
 data100
 data1000
 data101
 ...`

I need the outputs sorted 1-1000. Is this possible?

Comment: Your question seems to be truncated, can you update your question with this additional information?

Comment: I had to edit a few times due to some premature returns. It should update for you shortly.

Comment: @jstewartmitchel Updated the answer with a possible solution

Comment: @yate's solution will run an order of magnitude faster, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby:

```
ruby -e 'def get_i(f); f.gsub(/^.*\/data/, "").gsub(/\/file.frq$/, "").to_i; end;
    Dir.glob("/home/user/directory/data*/file.frq").sort{|a,b| get_i(a) <=> get_i(b)}.each{|f|
        File.readlines(f).each{|l| v = (Float(l.split[4]) rescue nil) and puts "#{f} #{(1-v).to_s}"}}'
```

I had this output on a test version:

```
/tmp/data1/file.frq 0.78
/tmp/data20/file.frq 0.78
/tmp/data1000/file.frq 0.78
```